# Would a switch matrix work with many buttons pressed?

Tags: circuit-design

I'm beginning the process of building a chess board that would detect piece movement and record it to a text file. My first idea for capturing piece movement would be a matrix of reed switches (set up similarly to those cheap membrane push button arrays used in arduino projects and such) and chess pieces with magnets on their bottoms.

My question is whether this setup would work when many switches are "on" at the same time, as there would be many pieces on the board at a time. If this would work, would a setup similar to those membrane keypads work, or would some "assistance chips" be needed?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: define "work" ...be clear about how you want it to work.

Comment: In order to detect switches independently when many are closed -- a.k.a. "N-key rollover" -- you need a diode (or something equivalent) in series with each switch.

Comment: @DaveTweed Does tri-state-able row/column allow OP's request?

Comment: I don’t think so; if there are pieces on A1, B1 and B2 then these rows and columns will be connected together, so it would be impossible to determine whether a piece was at A2.  Using diodes at each junction would probably be the simplest solution.

Comment: How do keyboards do it? Some commands need 3 or 4 keys pressed at the same time…

Comment: People have used the term but it's relevance may have been missed. Search for 'N  key rollover' for much discussion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you design the firmware well, the matrix can detect up to 2 multiple key presses.
Let's assume that matrix rows are wired to Port A, columns are wired to Port B.
Here's pseudo-code for it.

```
for X of PORTA {
    output HIGH on X
    for Y of PORTB {
        if Y is HIGH {
            process as button at (X, Y) is pressed
        }
    }
|
```

It is simple to implement, but you can use [Arduino KeyPad Library](https://github.com/Nullkraft/Keypad), which works pretty well.

Comment: Will this work when multiple buttons/switches are held down at the same time as well?

Comment: It depends on the definition of "same time". For example, if the MCU scans 8 rows and 8 columns, total 64 cycles. One cycle is less than 1us in any Arduino MCUs, thus, a whole scanning over 64 keys will be less than 64us.  In many human interface devices, 64us time difference can be considered as the "same time".

Comment: What I meant is would this matrix be able to detect if multiple switches are all pressed and held down at the same time, ex. if multiple chess pieces were on the switch matrix

Comment: @AlexanderBenton ... read this http://blog.komar.be/how-to-make-a-keyboard-the-matrix/

Comment: This is a poor answer. No firmware will work, if the hardware does not support reading an arbitrary amount of buttons. The firmware is not the issue, the hardware is.

Comment: With the above algorithm, diods are needless for detecting multiple keypresses.

Comment: Why claim that without proving it? So you don't see that pushing 3 buttons of a square will also short out the wires of 4th button in the square even if the button is not pressed? Which is exactly why diodes are needed to distinguish multiple button presses, in this case, 32 simultaneous switches out of 64.

Comment: For 3+ multiple button presses, you're right. With this algorithm, 2 multiple keypresses work fine.

Comment: So why did you think this answer would be useful in an application in which 32 of the 64 switches are closed at the start?

Comment: It was my misunderstanding of "many buttons" as two simultaneous presses.
For 3+ multiple presses, using diodes are mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

If the hardware has only a button matrix, the hardware won't allow reading of more than 2 arbitrary buttons at any given time, because if three buttons happen to be pressed so that they form a square for example, there is no way to deduce if the fourth button of the square is pressed or not, as the pins of the fourth button are already shorted by the three other buttons.

If the hardware has diodes for each button, then it will be possible to read each and every button individually.

Comment: Diods are not needed if firmware scans X-Y seperately.

Comment: @HotteShen If you say so, then please explain how it is possible to distinquish multiple switches simultaneously, as the point is to determine where 32 pieces are on a chessboard.

Answer (score 1):

For a X-Y simple switch matrix, the simple answer is NO. With added diode, Yes.
When you energize a ROW one at time, you can read the Column that is energized by a key stroke.  IF you press any number of keys on a single Row or single Column, you will be able to detect each one of them.  When you press two keys in different Row and column let’s say “E4”, and “D5”. When you energized Row 5, column D will be energized by the press of “D5”, same goes for column “E” when Row 4 is energized. So far so good.  Now when you pressed a third key at an intersection let’s say “D4”. When you energize Row 5, column “D” will be energized by the press of “D5” and Row 4 will also be energized by the key “D4”. When Row 4 is energized, Row 5 will also be energized the same way. The third key will be read in both position “D4” and “E5”.
Two prevent the unintended activation of another Row by a Key press, a diode placed is series with each switch will isolated each Row.  In this configuration, reading of all switched even if pressed simultaneously will be possible.